# Getting the error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a controller AddPrice which I call from a Price listing screen as a popup using the $uibModal.open call and passing in the controller.
Controller is not defined in the addPrice.html

addPrice.html

```
<div>
  <form>
    <!-- contains UI controls but controller is not mentioned in this page -->
  </form>
</div>
```

addPriceController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'addPriceController';

    angular.module('myApp').controller(controllerId, [
      '$scope',
      '$q',
      '$uibModalInstance',
      addPriceController]);

    function addPriceController(
        $scope,
        $q, 
        modalInstance) {

    }
}) ();
```

The above scenario works fine.

Now I want to reuse addPrice.html in a different ManagePrice.html screen as an "in-page" edit and NOT as a pop up.

I added the following in ManagePrice.html:

```
<div ng-include src="'addPrice.html'"
     ng-controller="addPriceController">
```

But I keep getting following error:

> angular.js:15018 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- addPriceController

How can I inject $uibModalInstance in this scenario?

OR

Is this not allowed in Angular JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$uibModalInstance` object is an injectable of controllers instantiated by the `$uibModal` service. It is not injected in controllers instantiated by the $compile service.

From the DOCs:

> ## $uibModal's open function
>
> ### options parameter
>
> - `controller` *(Type: `function|string|array`, Example: `MyModalController`)* - A controller for the modal instance, either a controller name as a string, or an inline controller function, optionally wrapped in array notation for dependency injection. Allows the controller-as syntax. Has a special `$uibModalInstance` injectable to access the modal instance.

For more information, see

- [Angular UI Bootstrap - Modal Directive API Reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps others in same kind of situation. The best solution would be to make this a directive. Then make another modal directive which would load the first directive. Basically there would be a `<edit-price>` and `<edit-price-modal>` directives restricted to element type ('E')